# Notepad++ How do I remove a break and join 2 lines together?

Tags: notepad++, replacement

My chat log has unnecessarily added a line break between timestamp and usernames / messages. Not sure if this is to be fixed in "Find & Replace" or "Line Operations".

**Basically I want this:**

> 16:53
>
> Admin: I mean ghosts are better at tasks
>
> 16:54
>
> Admin: nah
>
> 16:56
>
> Admin:  Michelle hey!

**To look something like this:**

> 16:53 Admin: I mean ghosts are better at tasks
>
> 16:54 Admin: nah
>
> 16:56 Admin: Michelle hey!

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: so there's a blank line between all lines as well?

Comment: no the Q&A added the space between the logs automatically. I wasn't able to get rid of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Replace and regular Expression in combination. In case all lines start in front without spaces you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\d{2}:\d{2})\R\R`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

Please note the space at the end of `\1` .

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! That worked great. SuperUser added the blank lines between the timestamps automatically when pasting those into my question. I removed the additonal "\R" at the end and your script worked perfectly!!